# resize an image inside a card

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic app and I got problem with  and image inside it.
I got a card with a fixed size I wanted and I want to put an image inside it.
I added the image (400x400 in size) but I can't resize it to fit inside the card.
This is the code:

```css
   page-home {
        ion-card{
            min-height: 47%;
            max-height: 47%;
        }
    
        .itemImage{
            padding: 2px;
            max-height: 10%;
        }
    }
```

```html
 <ion-content>
    
      <ion-card>
        <div class="itemImage">
          <img src="assets/img/placeholder.png">
        </div>
      </ion-card>
    
      <ion-card>
      </ion-card>
    
    </ion-content>
```

this is how it looks:[image: as you can see it take the whole card]

Answer (score 0):

add width:100% to .itemImage and .itemImage >img.

Comment: thanks, I tried but it didn't work, the picture still won't resize itself to the size I want.

Answer (score 0):

I would add:

```
.itemImage img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what i added too

Comment: thanks, I tried but it didn't work, the picture still won't resize itself to the size I want.